# git: two user's mentioned in one commit

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, squash

I am trying to correctly rebase a git history that has been already pushed to the remote.  Everything has worked as expected, except there is a mysterious "two users" mentioned in the commits that I `squash`-ed. The diff of this commit matches that of the changes made by user `tpgmartin`, in this images case.

Here is the screenshot of what I see on github (I'm user `ahoskins`):

[image]

Why is this behaviour happening?

Comment: Are you wondering when/why github shows both author and committer?  Or are you wondering what the difference is between author and committer, or do you have some other question?

Comment: I'm wondering what it means to have both an author and committer?  And in the context of this commit, why would this commit be affected by squashing a different commit?

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6755824/1256452