# Get all commits from GitHub using Java API

Tags: java, github, github-api

I want to get all commits from GitHub using Java API. So far I managed to create this simple code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.eclipse.egit.github.core.Repository;
import org.eclipse.egit.github.core.client.GitHubClient;
import org.eclipse.egit.github.core.service.RepositoryService;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class GithubImplTest
{
    public void testSomeMethod() throws IOException
    {
        GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient();
        client.setCredentials("sonratestw@gmail.com", "sono");

        RepositoryService service = new RepositoryService(client);

        List<Repository> repositories = service.getRepositories();

        for (int i = 0; i < repositories.size(); i++)
        {
            Repository get = repositories.get(i);
            System.out.println("Repository Name: " + get.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

How I can get all commits into the repository from this account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [Eclipse GitHub Java API](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core) you are using, the class [`CommitService`](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/v4.4.0.201606070830-r/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/CommitService.java) provides access to repository commits. The method [`getCommits(repository)`](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/v4.4.0.201606070830-r/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/CommitService.java#L69) can be invoked to retrieve the list of all commits for the given repository.

Sample code to print all commits of a repository:

```
CommitService commitService = new CommitService(client);
for (RepositoryCommit commit : commitService.getCommits(repository)) {
    System.out.println(commit.getCommit().getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I can get time of commit?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Yes, you can use `commit.getCommit().getCommitter().getDate()` (or `commit.getCommit().getAuthor().getDate()` to retrieve the date at which the commit was made ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755824/what-is-the-difference-between-author-and-committer-in-git) the difference between author and committer).

Comment: One last question. Is there a way to get all commits from today or a range of days?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Hmm I don't know of a direct way to do that. [Git API itself provides a way](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/) with the `since` and `until` parameter. Could be possible to subclass `CommitService` and add a new `getCommits` that supports those parameters ([like done here for the others](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/v4.4.0.201606070830-r/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/CommitService.java#L134-L156)). Best to ask a separate question if you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

For a given repository, you can use JGit `git.log()` function ([`LogCommand`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/LogCommand.html)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidRefNameException, GitAPIException {
    try (Repository repository = CookbookHelper.openJGitCookbookRepository()) {
        try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
            Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().all().call();
            int count = 0;
            for (RevCommit commit : commits) {
                System.out.println("LogCommit: " + commit);
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your Eclipse version, you would need the [`jgit-core` maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1.201607150455-r</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know what maven dependency I need to import?

Comment: @PeterPenzov yes: jgit-core: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit

Comment: how did you get the CookbookHelper here ?

Comment: @TanmoyBhattacharjee That is an example from JGit Cookbook: https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/33b0eaaa5ce9538aaf808a0d9aa4c389973b2cf5/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/WalkAllCommits.java#L35-L48.  That project has a CookbookHelper class https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/33b0eaaa5ce9538aaf808a0d9aa4c389973b2cf5/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/helper/CookbookHelper.java#L26