# Commiter in git some clarification

Tags: git, github

Is the commiter of the git is the real person who did the`push to git` ? 
I know that for specified commit there is `author` and in addition there is `commiter`. I search and find that there is the option to push several commits from several users, so is the commiter who the one that acatully `mearge and push` to git ?

I read the following post and still it not clear if 
[Difference between author and committer in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750808/difference-between-author-and-committer-in-git)

in the post it writes as answer:

`assumed to be the person who committed the code` what is commited ? pushed ?

Comment: @StegSchreck - Did you read my post ? I’ve already add it as link …

Comment: I did. And I think the answer is already in there. Usually, committer and author are the same. But you can set the author of a code-change by using the `--author` option in a commit. This should indicate who wrote the code. The committer is the one on created the commit by using `git commit`.
Maybe this post makes it clearer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755824/what-is-the-difference-between-author-and-committer-in-git

Comment: It doesn't matter if you already read that post, your question is an *exact* duplicate. You need to come up with a substantially different question if you want to make a new post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the commiter of the git is the real person who did the push ...?

No.

Every commit stores some metadata.  Here is a recent commit to the Git repository for Git, for instance:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 8ccb7d4fa49449a843b00aca64baf99feb10e2ab
parent e7e80778e705ea3f9332c634781d6d0f8c6eab64
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1516742470 -0800
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1516742470 -0800

First batch after 2.16

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

As in the other answers, the *author* string is intended to describe the person who wrote the code in question—the code itself is under the `tree`—while the *committer* string is intended to describe the person who stored the code in a repository using the `git commit` verb.  Neither has anything to do with a person who ran `git push`, because you don't create a *new* commit using `git push`.

The `git push` verb is for transporting existing commits (and/or other Git objects) from one repository to another.  The `git fetch` verb does the same kind of thing, except that the direction of transport is reversed.  (And remember, `git pull` just means: *Run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command, usually `git merge`.*)  If you wish to record the identity of someone running a transport command like `git push`, you need to use or augment your transport software (ssh, secure web server, etc) so as to record this information.

Note that the person who creates a commit has complete and total control over what goes into the new commit, *including both author and committer strings*.  These strings are not automatically authenticated.  If you wish to authenticate them, you can make additional requirements on the message data—the text after the first blank line in the commit object.  (This is not part of Git itself, though Git knows how to run PGP commands that create or verify digital signatures.  The example commit above does not have any such digital signature.)  When you are receiving commits and/or other Git objects, either as the recipient of `git push` or the initiator of `git fetch`, you have some control—via Git's *hooks* for push-recipients—over whether to accept the new objects.  (As the initiator of a `git fetch` you don't have any hooks, but you have complete control of the repository both before and after the fetch.)

#### Summary

The `git commit` verb creates new commit objects (and, often, additional Git objects).  The committer is the person who runs `git commit`—and as the committer, that person chooses the strings to be used here.  The author is the same person, unless the committer chooses otherwise.

The `git push` verb activates a transport system, usually via SSH or HTTPS (though Git cares only about transporting data, and you can even use `git bundle` to split the transport into "write" and later "read" phases so as to transport the data on punched-cards or whatever other crazy system you like).  The transport system carries existing commits and other Git objects from one Git to another Git.  To make the transport as fast as possible, if the connection between the two Gits is interactive, the two Gits can exchange information about which commits and other objects they have, and hence figure out who should receive which objects that they *don't* have.

It's up to the recipient to do any verification required.  Often, there is none: if the transport itself is authenticated, the receiver simply trusts the transport's authentication.  Since commit hash IDs form a [Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree), the transport-specific authentication is often sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for elborating answer , just to make sure. the person who do the push can be other person from the author and the commiter and this person data is not stored in the git metaata ?  or other place .

Comment: Yes, the person doing the push (or non-person if the push is fully automated) can be quite different from the author and/or committer of any or all of the commits being transferred.

Comment: thanks, and the the user who done the `push` is stored anywhare on git ? if yes which entity ?

Comment: No. The user, if any, who did the `git push` is *not* stored. (Not in Git at least. The transport authentication system *may* store it somewhere, outside Git.)